# How to stop JetPack from spilling script on browser

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, jetpack

I'm trying to use jet-pack for comments but every time I activate it, it spills scrips on my page. Something like below and a lot more on the footer.

```
img#wpstats{display:none}
/* <![CDATA[ */ var wpNotesIsJetpackClient = true; var wpNotesIsJetpackClientV2 = true; /* ]]> */
```

[See the footer here](http://nollytale.hostalone.com/third-interview-card/)

I have tried all the suggestions I found online but to no avail, any ideas on how this can be solved.

Comment: For more specific answers for WordPress related questions ask here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, Prakash Pazhanisamy.